# Assigned to do a physically demanding job with someone who wasn't up for it. Manager mad things were slow and may have to do it with them again

Tags: management, colleagues

I'm going to phrase this question in a blunt way. I was assigned to do a tasks that had a considerable amount of physical work. I'm male and in good shape but I'm not particularly "large". A smaller lady was assigned to work with me.

She helped with some of the physical tasks but didn't even try some of the time. For example there was a table that needed people to hold it at both ends to move. It wasn't even that it was heavy, it was more about balancing it. I basically had to ask random strangers if they could help in order to get the job done. The manager was upset that things were behind schedule. I may have to work with this lady again. She kept telling the manager that 2 people wasn't enough to do the job but certainly 2 fit people could do it. I do not know if she was unwilling or unable to do the lifting, but I think if she tried hard she would have been able to do it.

I may be assigned to do a similar task with her again. Should I say anything to the manager? I have a really bad sense with these things. Should I say "I know Ms.X said 2 people was not enough to do the physical part of the job but I think she wasn't comfortable or not able to physically exert herself"...I know that sounds silly.

To be clear, this job isn't mainly a physical job. I think in any job something physical comes up from time to time though (like moving a table, boxes etc). The manager is in a different city and hasn't met me (or probably my coworker) in person so may not know how "big" we are, or how much physical work was involved in the task.

From Op comment: so basically the job was sales/marketing related. We had to set up a presentation and this involved setting up a table, moving some boxes, setting up a poster etc

Comment: "I do not know if she was unwilling or unable to do the lifting, but I think if she tried hard she would have been able to do it...To be clear, this job isn't mainly a physical job." It would be helpful to mention what the job actually is. It's a bad idea for everyone involved to have people do tasks they are unfit to do and risk injury.

Comment: @jcm so basically the job was sales/marketing related. We had to set up a presentation and this involved setting up a table, moving some boxes, setting up a poster etc

Comment: @BitFred: You should edit your comment above into the answer. It's very helpful to have that contextual detail.

Comment: I'm curious, do the job requirements mention needing to be able to lift a certain amount of weight? Jobs that require occasional lifting usually say something about being able to lift 25lbs - 50lbs.

Comment: Lots of missing details here - Are either of you employed to do any type of manual work / moving heavy objects etc? Have both of you been trained on appropriate techniques? Are you insured for this type of activity?

Comment: Just a comment that even if an employee looks like they may be able to except themselves to complete a task, they may be carrying some sort of injury/impairment that makes them unable to reach 100% of their potential. For instance, they may be able to move a few boxes around, but lifting a table that may take 100% of their capacity may be a bridge too far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is, whoever is doing this job is being paid to do the job.  If the job takes 2 people, but 3 people are assigned to it, because 1 of those people is not effective at doing the  job (for any reason, physical, mental, emotional), then, simply  put, the  company is spending money ineffectively,  by paying an extra person who doesn't need to be there (and could instead be doing something more productive).

For this reason, you should raise this issue with your manager.  It's not an issue of "Jane can't lift stuff, I don't want to work with her", it's an issue of "Bob and I can do this lifting work more efficiently than Jane and I, so if Bob is assigned to this task instead of Jane, then the work will be done more efficiently, and Jane can work on other tasks that need her attention".  Raising this issue  to your manager without some discussion/speculation on Jane's physical fitness may be difficult so that might enter into the discussion, but the focus should not be on Jane's  fitness or lack thereof, and should be instead on maximizing productivity of everyone to get the job (the more general "the job", meaning the general work of the company and not this task in particular) done.

Answer (score 33):

Analyse the task beforehand. If there is heavy lifting involved ask for more help from the manager citing previous issues getting it accomplished.

> She kept telling the manager that 2 people wasn't enough to do the job

She knows her own limitations, and she gave fair warning in my opinion. Next time she does that I suggest you back her up.

Comment: Good point. I didn't mention this was all last minute and we hadn't seen the assets before hand and the manager is in a different city. I had thought the manager would have analyzed the task before hand.

Answer (score 2):

The comments clarify that this was setting up a sales presentation. In many such cases, there are professional people available to be hired for such tasks. In many vendor packets for shows, they give contact information for hiring the right people for unloading and setting up the booths.

This is a situation where the sales people do not have the physical capabilities to do what management wants them to do and the correct people should have been and should be hired in the future.

Comment: Think about this situation. A sales presentation that needs a setup is likely going after a $50,000 to $250,000 sale. A sales manager who is not willing to spend the money ($100-$250) to get the right people in for the presentation setup should be fired.

Answer (score 2):

Workplace safety rules should be pretty clear on how much lifting can be expected from employees, and how much lifting your insurance will allow, depending on available tools and instruction on their use.

Since I have an office job, those numbers are pretty low for me, IIRC around 10 kg is part of my job duties, and up to 25 kg is allowed provided I wear boots with steel-capped toes. The people on the shop floor can transport way heavier goods, because they have a pallet jack and a forklift, and are instructed in their use.

Anything outside these parameters is considered unsafe, and will cause the wrath of the insurance lawyers. We do not go there.

If this is becoming a somewhat regular thing in your job, it makes sense to invest in safety equipment, at least safety shoes and gloves for a better grip, ideally also work clothes that do not tear easily and that belong to the company, so there is no issue of responsibility for damage to clothing.

The latter is likely the issue why Ms. X seemed "unwilling" to do lifting.

Getting proper work clothes for whoever will be responsible for setting tables will resolve that problem either by allowing her to do that work without risk to her personal property, or by the boss designating someone else for the task so they have to buy fewer pieces of equipment.

If you outsourced the job to a contractor, they would be wearing proper safety equipment as well, and they know what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

> It wasn't even that it was heavy, it was more about balancing it.

It isn't your place to speculate about her physical capability based on your assessment of what is, and what is not, heavy. In fact, it isn't your place to speculate about or judge her physical capability at all.

Simply tell the manager that the task requires more than two people. It's then up to them to decide how it should be handled.

Comment: To elaborate on your first sentence: Even if the coworker was 6'4", 250 lb male and apparently very fit, if they say it's too much it's not your place to speculate.  Maybe they have an injury or illness.  They probably have no obligation to disclose it to anyone but supervisors, HR or others as specifically dictated by company policy.

Comment: It is true that it is not OP's  place to speculate about his coworker's physical ability.   However, if he knows (based on this  experience) that, if this coworker is assigned to this task, then the task is likely to  not get done effectively,  it is his place to suggest to his manager that this coworker not be assigned to this task.   If the coworker is going to slack off instead of doing their assigned work while being "on the clock", then the manager should know about that and, at least,  assign that coworker to do something else while on the clock.

Comment: "speculate about or judge her physical capability at all." it is an objective fact she did not do any physical work

Comment: Her not performing the work is immaterial to the OP making a judgment of her physical capability based on his assessment of the physical capacity required to perform the task. **It wasn't even that it was heavy** is, in essence, a subjective opinion about the physical capacity required to perform the task. He isn't in a position to make a judgment of someone else's physical capacity to perform a task.

Comment: @joeqwerty You're really white knighting here of all places? A task was given to two people, one person could do it and the other sat around complaining.  The fact that the complainer is a female and the OP is a male is clouding your judgment in your attempt to defend her.  Pathetic answer.

Comment: @Jack My answer and my comments aren't in defense of anyone. They're a statement that it isn't the place of the OP, or anyone else, to make judgments and/or assessments of what is, and what is not, within another persons physical capacity. Not sure why you're not understanding that.

Comment: Joeqwerty, I think you are very wrong here. If two people want to move the table, it is absolutely appropriate for one person to say that the other one isn’t up to it. Unless you claim that person is lying.

Comment: What a stupid answer.  So what if the OP gets another dud of a coworker that can't help move a table? Oh 3 people aren't enough, we need 4 people.  And the next person is another frail human that isn't up to the task? We need 5 people! Maybe the OP should call his coworker "Queen" and ask her to give him orders.  OP is clearly just a slave that obeys in your eyes.  A man chooses, a slave obeys.

Comment: @Jack You sound angry. Maybe try taking a long walk off of a short pier to cool yourself off.

Answer (score 1):

You might be proactive and ask around if any of your co-workers would be willing to help out. Someone who loves going to the gym, not a little 5'2" lady.